# Losing Session Variable forwarding from jsp to servlet

Tags: java, jsp, session, servlets

I'm struggling with a rather troublesome problem. I'm making a web application using the following jsp/servlets.

GameServlet
Scene.jsp
PageServlet

GameServlet creates a new HttpSession and then sets a number of attributes I expect to use later.

GameServlet then forwards to Scene.jsp using the following code:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("cur_game", game);
        session.setAttribute("logic", logic);
        session.setAttribute("cur_scene", scene);
        session.setAttribute("session_id", session.getId());
        out.println("Loaded session attributes");
        if (debug == null) {
            String target = "/Scene.jsp";
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(target);
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
```

In Scene.jsp I display the session id for later comparison. This works and also displays the other attributes in the session.

Then a button calls a function using the following code:

```
<script>
function gotoPage(target)
{
    Str = "PageServlet?page=" + target;
    window.location = Str;
}
</script>
```

However PageServlet doesn't seem to recognise the previous session. I check with this with the following code:

```
HttpSession sesh = request.getSession(false);

        if(sesh==null)
            out.println("Session is Null!");
        else
            out.println("<br/>Session id: " + sesh.getId());
```

And currently it displays that "Session is Null"

If anybody could provide some help it would greatly appreciated!

Many Thanks

Alex

Comment: What session tracking are you using? Header? Cookie? URL rewriting? I suspect it's the latter and you are not using the appropriate method to rewrite the URL to add the session information.

Comment: what is debug variable? is it not null? did you try with request.getSession() by removing false?>

Comment: TBh I didn't realise there are different types of session tracking? I thought the browser just knows that there is a session for that website. I don't store the session I'd in the url and not sure what a header session is so guess it's a cookie? What would be the best way to track session?     The debug varibles was simply to let get all the error and info codes in the servlet . When I do get session without false it creates a new session I'd.